# Proof of equivalance beginning with the geometrical definition of the scalar (dot) product and the algebraic definition of the dot product.

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Geometrically the dot product is defined to be 
|x| |y| cosθ where |x| |y| are the magnitudes of the two vectors in question. Can anyone prove, beginning with this geometrical definition, an equivalence between it and the algebraic definition of the dot product?

Comment: Wikipedia can
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for.